# Avoid comparison from conditional statements

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

Hi I'm trying to filter records on the basis of Brand,Flavor,Price,Size,Type. i am using a single form to handle this so if user filter only by brand then rest of options like price,flavor will be unchecked so i am checking if Brand or flavor or price is null.I got the solution but i have make lot of comparisons for all cases. i need a solution by which i have make less comparisons.I am using following code

```
  public List<Products> Filter_Items(String[] Brand, String[] Flavour,Float Price,String Size,String Type)
{

    ResultSet rs;
    List<Products> data = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    try {
        StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
        if (Brand != null) {
            for (String str : Brand) {
                param.append("'").append(str).append("', ");
            }
        }
        StringBuilder param1 = new StringBuilder();
        if (Flavour != null) {
            for (String str : Flavour) {
                param1.append("'").append(str).append("', ");
            }
        }

        String prm = param.toString().length() > 2 ? param.toString()
                .substring(0, param.toString().length() - 2) : null;
        String prm1 = param1.toString().length() > 2 ? param1.toString()
                .substring(0, param1.toString().length() - 2) : null;

        String query = "select  * from products where ";

        if (prm != null && prm1 != null) {
            query += "Brand in (" + prm + ") and Flavour in (" + prm1 + ")";
        } else if (prm != null && prm1 == null) {
            query += "Brand in (" + prm + ")";
        } else if (prm1 != null && prm == null) {
            query += "Flavour in (" + prm1 + ")";
        }

        stmt = DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs != null) {
            data = new ArrayList<Products>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Products p = new Products();
                p.setTitle(rs.getString("Ttile"));
                p.setCategory(rs.getString("Category"));
                p.setSubCategory(rs.getString("SubCategory"));
                p.setSubCategoryTwo(rs.getString("SubCategorytwo"));
                p.setPrice(rs.getInt("Price"));
                p.setFlavour(rs.getString("Flavour"));
                p.setSize(rs.getString("Size"));
                p.setImage(rs.getString("image"));
                p.setBrand(rs.getString("Brand"));
                p.setInstock(rs.getString("instock"));
                p.setInstockQty(rs.getInt("instockqty"));
                data.add(p);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());

        return null;
    }
    return data;

}


}
```

Comment: Note: `PreparedStatement`s provide some protection against SQL injection and some performance gains **if properly used**. You are not using them properly (embedding the unsanitized parameters in the SQL).

Comment: ok so tell me how to use properly

Comment: Read my comment carefully. It explains what you are doing wrong. BTW... next time someone explains something to you, try to think about it more than 1 minute before postint a "tell me how to ... " comment.

Comment: SORRY IF YOU MIND .I DIDN'T SAY IN THAT SENSE. I DON'T HAVE MUCH EXPERIENCE IN WORKING WITH SQL .

Answer (score 0):

You can use as always third party libraries for validation like javax validation or any other more specialized on this.
You could create a bean of your data with all the getters and setters and apply validation on your bean.

To pass arrays you need getters and setters like this one:

```
public class Foo {
    private int[] array;

    public Foo(int[] array) {
        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }

    /** @param the array to use */
    public setArray(int[] array) {
        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }

    /** @return a copy of the array */
    public int[] getArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }
}
```

To validate a bean see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) tutorial.

Comment: actually i am passing an array how do genrate setters for passing an array

Comment: can you please how can i apply validation using bean or javax

Comment: ultimatly i am checking for all the filter parametres like type size price and all. even if its a bean

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to start naming variables according to what they are logically. Names like `prm` and `prm1` are meaningless, while `brand` and `flavor` make more sense as variable names since that's what's in them.

I don't see the number of comparisons as a problem.  But giving everything generic variable names and then not even indenting the if-statements makes my eyes glaze over.

How about something like this:

```
if (brand != null && flavor != null)  
{
    query += "Brand in (" + brand + ") and Flavour in (" + flavor + ")";
} 
else if (brand != null && flavor == null) 
{
    query += "Brand in (" + brand + ")";
} 
else if (flavor != null && brand == null) 
{
    query += "Flavour in (" + flavor + ")";
}
```

Edit:  One thing you can do is split your SQL into two variables, one for the main query and one for the where clause, then just add to the where clause like this:

```
private String addToWhereClause(String currentWhereClause, String fieldname, String value)
{
    String returnValue = "";
    if (value != null)
    {
        if(!"".equals(currentWhereClause))
        {
           returnValue += " AND ";
        }
        returnValue += " "+fieldname+" IN(" + value + ") ";
    }
    return returnValue;
}


String whereClause = "";
whereClause += addToWhereClause(whereClause, "Brand", brand);
whereClause += addToWhereClause(whereClause, "Flavour", flavor);
query = query + " " + whereClause;
```

Comment: but there are more comparisons like price,size,type i want design cases like if brand is null and others not and brand flavor is null but others not so is there any way where i can avoid this much comparsions

Comment: Edited the answer with something useful to your purposes.